# Splice in javascript is not deleting the correct element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array as given below:

```
[{MAP: "RTO", PNR: "OCYH", ID: "7311ba56-730a-478e-af6e-607d8dee6b0c", Number: "76809", checked: false}
{MAP: "RTO", PNR: "OCYH", ID: "280515e8-22e1-4365-92a5-20b8e5b8b62d", Number: "87661821", checked: false}
{MAP: "RTO", PNR: "ISMP", ID: "80f71c18-b530-46ca-9acb-798f73dcdde3", Number: "6343279", checked: false}
{MAP: "RTO", PNR: "ISMP", ID: "a9c607a3-d2f9-4643-822b-b9f25c229b92", Number: "5483292", checked: false}
{MAP: "RTO", PNR: "ISMP", ID: "e938c2c9-6eb9-472f-8e3a-d4529fd55f16", Number: "67698094", checked: false}
{MAP: "RTO", PNR: "ISMP", ID: "55ea118b-beea-4407-84cf-3aebc98bffd2", Number: "15201901", checked: false}
{MAP: "RTO", PNR: "TNAT", ID: "387b3710-901d-45f2-a38b-b875237e1210", Number: "15201902", checked: false}]
```

Based on value of checked box click,value of checked changes.

I am trying to add all the checked true value to an array and remove the value if the checked is turned as false.I have used splice to do so but it is not removing the correct ID.

```
var singleTransactionCollection=[];


constructor(){
super()
this.state={
singleCheckedList:[]
}
}

 handleCheckbox = (Id, checked) => {
    if (checked) {
      singleTransactionCollection.push(this.state.items.filter(obj => {
  return obj.ID ==transactionId
        }));
      this.setState({ singleCheckedList: singleTransactionCollection});
    } else {
      this.state.singleCheckedList.splice(this.state.singleCheckedList.findIndex(item => ID !== transactionId), 1)//Not returning the expected result

      this.setState({ singleCheckedList: singleTransactionCollection });
    }
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.map(item => {
        return {
          ...item,
          checked:
            item.ID === transactionId ? !item.checked : item.checked
        };
      })
    });
  };

render(){
return(
<div>
<Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input
                      onChange={this.selectAll}
                      type="checkbox"
                      checked={this.state.selectAll}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </th>
              <th>TransactionId</th>
              <th>PNR</th>
              <th>Source</th>
              <th>InvoiceNo</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {items
              .map((item, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td id="col1" align="center">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      checked={item.checked ? true : ""}
                      onChange={this.handleCheckbox.bind(
                        this,
                        item.ID,
                        !item.checked
                      )}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td id="col1" align="center">

                      {item.ID}

                  </td>
                  <td id="col2" align="center">
                    {item.PNR}
                  </td>
                  <td id="col5" align="center">
                    {item.MAP}
                  </td>
                  <td id="col6" align="center">
                    {item.Number}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
          </tbody>
                  </Table>
</div>
)
}
```

My java script function to remove the item is not working as expected when checked is turned false after making it true.

Any suggestions where I am going wrong.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is `ID` in `item => ID !== transactionId`? Looks like a typo - did you mean `item.ID`?

Comment: why not using the filter for else case also instead of splice and findIndex, also splice with modify the original state array which is anti pattern, avoid doing that.

Comment: Shouldn't `ID !== transactionId` be `Id !== transactionId`?

Comment: @JackBashford I doubt it - it's still going to run the same check against every element, so it would either return `0` or `-1` - nothing else.

Comment: @VLAZ...yes it should be item.ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule you probably don't want to splice an array directly from the state (react works using an immutable philosophy).
In addition, you probably shouldn't constantly modify a global array. Using the spread function you can create a copy of your `this.state.singleCheckedList` and play with it freely.

```
constructor(props) { 
  super(props); // I know you aren't using any props in this class but as a best practice, you should pass the props in your ctor so you won't forget
  this.state={
    singleCheckedList: [],
    items: [
      {MAP: "RTO", PNR: "OCYH", ID: "7311ba56-730a-478e-af6e-607d8dee6b0c", Number: "76809", checked: false},
      {MAP: "RTO", PNR: "OCYH", ID: "280515e8-22e1-4365-92a5-20b8e5b8b62d", Number: "87661821", checked: false},
      {MAP: "RTO", PNR: "ISMP", ID: "80f71c18-b530-46ca-9acb-798f73dcdde3", Number: "6343279", checked: false},
      {MAP: "RTO", PNR: "ISMP", ID: "a9c607a3-d2f9-4643-822b-b9f25c229b92", Number: "5483292", checked: false},
      {MAP: "RTO", PNR: "ISMP", ID: "e938c2c9-6eb9-472f-8e3a-d4529fd55f16", Number: "67698094", checked: false},
      {MAP: "RTO", PNR: "ISMP", ID: "55ea118b-beea-4407-84cf-3aebc98bffd2", Number: "15201901", checked: false},
      {MAP: "RTO", PNR: "TNAT", ID: "387b3710-901d-45f2-a38b-b875237e1210", Number: "15201902", checked: false}
    ] // You tried to reference your items list from the state but you didn't actually declare it as part of your class
  };
}

/*
  1. In your code you referenced transactionId so I assume you meant to put that here instead of Id
  2. I also added the itemIndex here so you won't need to traverse the entire items array again to change the checkedState
*/
handleCheckbox = (transactionId, checked, itemIndex) => {
  const items = [...this.state.items]; // Using the spread function (...) I can crate a duplicate of the original array to manipulate freely
  const arrayToManipulate = [...this.state.singleCheckedList]; // Again, using the spread function
  items[itemIndex].checked = checked; // Now that we have the passed index you don't need to check that you are at the right item in order to change the checked status, just insert the new status
if (checked) {
    arrayToManipulate.push(items[itemIndex]);
  } else {
    const index = arrayToManipulate.findIndex(item => item.ID === transactionId); // You are trying to find the matching index, so you should be checking for a matching pair ===
    arrayToManipulate.splice(index, 1);
  }

  this.setState({ singleCheckedList: arrayToManipulate, items }); // React is smart, it will try to minimize the amount of times it touches the state, so combining your changes together will make sure you get the expected result
};

render() {
  const { items } = this.state; // You referenced items in here while never actually bringing it from the state like you did in your handle function
  return(
    <div>
      <Table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <input
                    onChange={this.selectAll}
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={this.state.selectAll}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th>TransactionId</th>
            <th>PNR</th>
            <th>Source</th>
            <th>InvoiceNo</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            items.map((item, i) => (
              <tr key={i}>
                <td id="col1" align="center">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={item.checked} // the checked propery is a boolean, you might as well just pass it seeing as you are changing it in your handle function
                    onChange={this.handleCheckbox.bind(this, item.ID, !item.checked, i)} // Notice I added the item index prop
                  />
                </td>
                <td id="col1" align="center">  
                  {item.ID}
                </td>
                <td id="col2" align="center">
                {item.PNR}
                </td>
                <td id="col5" align="center">
                {item.MAP}
                </td>
                <td id="col6" align="center">
                {item.Number}
                </td>
            </tr>))
          }
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This wont work because result of filter will give array of array and when applying findIndex on that ,it will always give -1.We need to get the array using reduce I guess

Comment: You're right, my mistake. In any case you don't actually need the filter because we've got the itemIndex (fixed the answer to match). If you want to make things even simpler, we can just pass the item to the function. Also moved the change in checked status up so you'll insert the new item